Enable_Precise_Upscale Function in OpenCV's SIFT
I am currently going through the OpenCV documentation for SIFT, and arrived on this function in the create portion of SIFT.
enable_precise_upscale: Whether to enable precise upscaling in the scale pyramid, which maps index 
x to 2x. This prevents localization bias. The option is disabled by default.

Can someone please explain what the definition of enable_precise_upscale is? What scale pyramid is this referring to and what is localization bias? Preferably in simpler terms than the academic papers I'm looking through now :).

as a basis for discussion, first read the SIFT paper. https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf -- you don't really need us to tell you what a scale pyramid is. you found descriptions of that already. what specific problems did you have with them?

I've read the paper but I'm not quite sure what precise upscaling or localization bias means in the description.

those are mere implementation details that have exceedingly little effect on the results, and rarely anybody even perceives it. this is only relevant to those people that don't just know what subpixel accuracy is, but people that actually must deal with it because their application is sensitive to it. -- you can try it, but watch the required processing time. it'll probably take longer. don't just think it's better because it sounds better. figure out whether it actually makes a difference to your application, and whether that's a positive or negative difference.
